# Advice on making this swoosh effect through text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path

I was wondering if I could get some advice on how I could achieve this cool swish effect in Illustrator.

[image: ELGAR swoosh text effect]

I know I can convert to outlines, and then modify each path but this required a lot of absolute precision, perhaps this is something that is not a quick win after all?

One could have more luck with the ability to mouse/pen through it at speed and then the text change as so but I doubt this will be this easy. You never know, however. I only just found out about 'copy merged' in Photoshop and that was worthy of a huge celebration :-)

Is there anything I should learn perhaps regarding this text effect? Something I can follow up on? To help me on my way? I am afraid 'Warping through text' and 'text swoosh effect' returns irrelevant results online.

Thanks (:

Comment: You may also want to see this answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99096/filter-script-or-effect-for-smudge-design/99100#99100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe Illustrator does have a **Warp Tool**.

Often this is merely to give you an overall guide which you can then refine afterwards. You do have to **Create Outlines** for any text (`Type > Create Outlines`).

[image]

Comment: You're wonderful.